# How to check firebase storage directory already exist

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage

How can I check if the Firebase Storage directory already exists in Flutter?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/list-files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to check if a "folder" exists in Cloud Storage.

This might sound strange, but you have to consider that folders don't actually exist in a bucket-based storage. *Cloud Storage doesn't actually have any folders*.

The files in the storage just have path metadata associated with them, so that we humans can think hierarchically like we do with folders.

If you want to know if a *file* exists (not a "folder"), then in your code you could `await getMetadata();` on a `StorageReference` that refers to the file you're looking for.

A workaround could be to create a dummy file such as "readme.md" inside each folder; that would certify its existence. If you can't find such file, your folder (probably) doesn't exist. This implies you carefully add such "dummy" file every time you add a folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
firebase.database().ref("path/node/").on('value', (snapshot) => { console.log(snapshot.exists()); });
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @venir is useful in understanding what's going on but you can overcome the problem by using this approach.

You can check if a folder exists by checking whether its parent folder contains a folder named after the one you are looking for. Something like this (excuse the TypeScript):

```
const beforeLast = (str: string, strLast: string) => {
  return str.substr(0, str.lastIndexOf(strLast))
}

const afterLast = (str: string, strLast: string) => {
  return str.substr(str.lastIndexOf(strLast) + 1)
}

private doesStorageFolderExist(storagePath: string): Observable<any> {
  const parentPath: string = beforeLast(storagePath, '/')
  const folderName: string = afterLast(storagePath, '/')
  const ref: AngularFireStorageReference = this.storage.ref(parentPath)
  const listAll: Observable<ListResult> = ref.listAll()

  return listAll.pipe(
    map((listResult: ListResult) => {
      const storagePathExists: boolean = listResult.prefixes.some((folderRef) => folderRef.name === folderName)
      return { storagePath, storagePathExists }
    })
  )
}
```

Obviously, this only works if there is a parent folder, but often this will be the case. You have to not like Firebase very much for making things so hard!